# How to convert a regular expression to return everything but what it was returning?

Tags: regex

The output of nm produces data I want to parse.   This expression works correctly: `grep -Po ' {9}U \K[^ ]+' test.txt`

Only returning the names after matching a line starting with:
`'         U '`

But now I want the opposite.  I want everything that doesn't match that, but only want the data starting from column 12 on.

How does one do that?

TIA!!

---

### Here's an Example (nm from a kernel module):

```
00000000 r ____versions  
000000a4 r __mod_alias38  
00000064 r __mod_author210  
00000034 r __mod_description211  
00000000 r __mod_license218  
000001b0 D __mod_pci_device_table  
00000080 r __mod_srcversion40  
000000dc r __mod_vermagic5  
00000024 r __mod_version216  
000000d0 r __module_depends  
00000000 D __this_module  
00000000 T cleanup_module  
00000000 d driver  
         U drm_core_get_map_ofs  
         U drm_core_get_reg_ofs  
         U drm_core_reclaim_buffers  
         U drm_exit  
         U drm_init  
         U drm_ioctl  
         U drm_mmap  
         U drm_open  
         U drm_poll  
         U drm_release  
00000000 T init_module  
000001b0 d pciidlist  
00000000 T vboxvideo_driver_load  
00000000 t vboxvideo_exit  
00000000 t vboxvideo_init
```

Running the command `grep -Po ' {9}U \K[^ ]+' sample.txt` on it gives:

```
drm_core_get_map_ofs  
drm_core_get_reg_ofs  
drm_core_reclaim_buffers  
drm_exit  
drm_init  
drm_ioctl  
drm_mmap  
drm_open  
drm_poll  
drm_release
```

But what I want is the other items like this:

```
____versions  
__mod_alias38  
__mod_author210  
__mod_description211 
etc..
```

Comment: post an example along with expected output.

Comment: [RegExr](http://regexr.com/) is a good resource for molding a regular expression to your will.

Comment: Yes, that site looks good for the future but doesn't seem to support \K in this case and I still wouldn't know how to do it.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question in the title, but if you're OK with sticking to grep, you can pass the -v option to grep.

Comment: adding -v to grep results in no lines being selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I appear to have figured it out:

`grep -Po '^(?! {9}U ).{11}\K[^ ]+' sample.txt`

gives the result I want.

Comment: To further this to add "and" type conditions you just add it after the prior condition.   Say you also don't want items that start with 8 zeros you can do: `grep -Po '^(?! {9}U )^(?!0{8}).{11}\K[^ ]+' sample.txt`